# Importing Data from MediaWiki to Wiki Module

Tags: import, wiki

I am currently using MediaWiki on my current site. On my new site I will be using ExpressionEngine and was wondering if there was an easy way to import data over to the Wiki Module http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/wiki/index.html

How should I pursue importing data from MediaWiki to the Wiki module in EE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way.  It is an involved data migration that you'd have to handle custom, unfortunately.